# Writing query inside a model

Tags: python, django, model

I want to write a query where if the Complete Status is all true , complete inside model Order should be automatically true. Can i write a query inside Order model using some methods or anything ? And can you suggest some help.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer , on_delete=models.SET_NULL , 
    null= True , blank = True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length= 100 , null=True)



class CompleteStatus(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.SET_NULL , 
null=True)
    seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    warehouse =models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pickup = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivered =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    received_by_customer =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: May I ask why `CompleteStatus` is a separate model and not a `status` field within `Order`?

Comment: Can an `Order` have multiple `CompleteStatus`ses? If not, then why is there not a `OneToOneField` from `CompleteStatus` to `Order`.

Comment: @Lewis I just had idea of doing this , where i can see true false for complete status

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the suggestion bro.. i corrected in mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it you want it so that whenever the `CompleteStatus` object is saved, you check to see if all Boolean fields are True. If they are, then you set `Order.complete` set to True.

In which case, you can simply edit the `save` method:

```py
class CompleteStatus(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    warehouse = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pickup = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    received_by_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.order and self.warehouse and self.pickup and self.delivered and self.received_by_customer:
            self.order.complete = True
            self.order.save(update_fields=['complete'])
```

You can also do:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def complete(self):
        if complete_status := self.completestatus
            return complete_status.warehouse and complete_status.pickup and complete_status.delivered and complete_status.received_by_customer

print(order.complete)
# True
```

but you won't be able to filter by the value then,

Comment: hey bro thanks for this help .. it worked just perfect .once again thank you :)

Comment: No probs! Can you accept it as the answer?

Comment: hey bro , if i want to say ,,
if self.ordercompletestatus.exists like in other places , in save method than what should i write . I want to make the method work only when self has ordercompletestatus model .